# пропадают атрибуты в jsp странице

Tags: jsp, servlet

При изучении servlets столкнулся с проблемой: имеется servlet, который передает на jsp страницу атрибуты, список:

```
req.setAttribute("name",list);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/list.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

jsp страница:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${name}" var="dev" >
    ${dev.id}<br>
    ${dev.firstName}<br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

все работает отлично, а когда я запускаю jsp, которая имеет ссылку на другую jsp страницу, описанную выше с помощью тэга `(<a href="list.jsp"/>)`, то она перестает отображать атрибуты, которые на нее переданы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Пишите параметр не в `request`, а в `session`, т. е. вместо:

   ```java
   req.setAttribute("name", list);
   ```

   надо:

   ```java
   req.getSession().setAttribute("name", list);
   ```
2. Тоже самое можно написать с помощью библиотеки [Java JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL)](http://java-online.ru/jsp-jstl.xhtml). На первой странице устанавливаем атрибут сессии:

   ```
   <c:set var="list" value="${name}" scope="session"/>
   ```

   на второй странице читаем:

   ```
   <c:out value="${sessionScope.list}"/>
   ```

---

Ссылка по теме: [How to pass data between JSP Pages using JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742401/how-to-pass-data-between-jsp-pages-using-jstl)